# Calling MSSQL function without specifying schema

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my Java program I have to call a stored prodedure called `FooBar(null)` . The program tries to be db platform independent. Some SQL statements are put together programmatically, one of them is:

```
insert into foo_bar (id, user, timestmp) values (1, 'foo', FooBar(null));
```

This works on Oracle, HSLQDB, MySQL. Now I have to make it work on MSSQL. I created the FooBar function. I log into the database with a user that has the default schema called `foo`.

This statement works only if I put the schema name before the function name:

```
insert into foo_bar (id, user, timestmp) values (1, 'foo', foo.FooBar(null));
```

If I log into the database then `exec FooBar(null)` works without `foo.`
Do you know how to avoid this `foo.` on MSSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike almost all other objects, DB functions must be fully qualified with the schema name in T-SQL.

If you're putting the statement together programmatically though, you can hack it to see if the JDBC driver is MSSQL and in that case, add the schema name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) eg

```
CREATE SYNOMYM FooBar FOR foo.FooBar;
```

If this fails, you're out of luck...